# Linux rename s/ - regex for wildcard single characte r

Tags: linux, terminal, rename

I have found a simple solution to my actual requirement, but I would still like to understand how to use the regex equivalent of the single character wildcard `?` which we use for filtering ... in say `ls`

I would like to rename a group of files which differ by one character.

**FROM**

```
Impossible-S01E01-x264.mkv
Impossible-S01E02-x264.mkv
Impossible-S01E03-x264.mkv
Impossible-S01E04-x264.mkv
Impossible-S01E05-x264.mkv
```

**TO**

```
Impossible-S01E01.mkv
Impossible-S01E02.mkv
Impossible-S01E03.mkv
Impossible-S01E04.mkv
Impossible-S01E05.mkv
```

As I said above, my simple solution is:

```
rename s/-x264// *.mkv
```

That sorts out my needs - all good and well - but I really want to understand my first approach:

To list the files, I can use:

```
ls Impossible-S01E0?-x264.mkv
```

So what I was trying for the rename was:

```
rename s/Impossible-S01E0?-x264.mkv/Impossible-S01E0?.mkv/ *.mkv
```

I have read up *here*:

[How do regular expressions differ from wildcards used to filter files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57957/how-do-regular-expressions-differ-from-wildcards-used-to-filter-files)

And *here*:

[Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y)

I see this:

> `.` matches any character (or any character except a newline).

I just can't seem to wrap my head around how to use that - hoping someone will explain for my education.

*{ edit: missed a backslash \ }*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, regular expressions aren't globs. If you wanted to keep the middle (e.g. catch the season/ep) and replace everything else, you'd need to use [capture groups](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#Capture-groups). e.g. `s/^.*(S\d+E\d+).*\.(.*?)$/Foo-$1.$2/`

This would extract an SxxExx and the file extension, throw everything else away, and compose a new filename.

In a bit more detail it:

1. Matches everything from the start until an SxxExx (where xx is actually any number of digits)
2. Captures the contents of SxxExx
3. Matches everything until the final literal `.`
4. Non-greedily matches everything after the `.`, which it captures.

For your specific case of removing a suffix, this is likely overkill, though.

Comment: That is clear and it makes sense. Agreed that it is overkill for the task at hand, but I will need this on other occasions. Thank you.